# Как поступить с центровкой элементов?

Tags: javascript, svg

В общем ситуация как обычно ...

Решил уже до конца разобраться с центровкой элементов программно

Есть `text` и некий `rect` я хочу именно программным способом вычислить центр этого `rect` и поставить точно в центр без смещения `text`

Какие есть способы для этого ?

Попытка из головы :

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#rect {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

#text {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="500">
  <rect id="rect" x="50" y="50" ></rect>
  <text id="text" x="130" y="105">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Не удивляйся потом, что в в FF не работает. Ты же уже сталкивался с данной проблемой `width` `height` в CSS для svg фигур поддерживает только Chtome, Opera, а может быть и другие web-kit браузеры с их экспериментальными технологиями Но другие браузеры не поддерживают.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT да я помню это ...пишу в основном в Хроме и по этому пока хочу понять только логику как центрировать а о кросс браузерности не думаю пока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужна центровка:

   ```
   alignment-baseline: middle;
   text-anchor: middle;
   ```
2. `getBBox()`;

```js
let box = rect.getBBox();
text.setAttribute('x', box.x + box.width/2);
text.setAttribute('y', box.y + box.height/2);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#rect {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

#text {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  fill: #000;
  alignment-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="500">
  <rect id="rect" x="50" y="50" width="200" height="200"></rect>
  <text id="text">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95803/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q-----).